# Mongo $exists query does not return correct documents

Tags: mongodb

Honestly, I don't understand how this is even possible:

```
> db.ts.find({"bcoded_metadata" : { "$exists" : true} } ).count()
199049
> db.ts.find({"bcoded_metadata" : { "$exists" : false} } ).count()
0
> db.ts.count()
2507873
```

I think sum of the first and second queries must be equal to the third.

I need to select from the collection all elements for which "bcoded_metadata" does not exist but the query returns nothing.
When I iterate this collection in the simple python script and manually check whether "bcoded_metadata" exists everything works as expected.

```
from pymongo import Connection
connection = Connection('127.0.0.1', 27017)
db = connection.data
c = 0
for item in db.ts.find():
    if not "bcoded_metadata" in item.keys():
            c+= 1
print c



python test.py 
2308824
```

This is correct answer.

Where is a source of problem?

indexes:

```
> db.ts.getIndexes();
[
        {
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "data.ts",
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "v" : 0
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("4f3c299b4c4a5ccfddbe4069"),
                "ns" : "data.ts",
                "key" : {
                        "last_seen" : 1
                },
                "name" : "last_seen_1",
                "v" : 0
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("4f3c2cef4c4a5ccfddbe406a"),
                "ns" : "data.ts",
                "key" : {
                        "attempts" : -1
                },
                "name" : "attempts_-1",
                "v" : 0
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("4f4279ed6aca13be31acbe6d"),
                "ns" : "data.ts",
                "key" : {
                        "bcoded_metadata" : 1
                },
                "name" : "bcoded_metadata_1",
                "sparse" : true,
                "v" : 0
        }
]
```

Comment: it is your query from the mongo shell or with a driver?

Comment: @marcolinux query is executed from the from shell. python script works via driver, obviously.

Comment: Maybe this bug? https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3918

Comment: @marcolinux It's indeed, thank you! But what kind of temporal solution should I use? the link does not provide any.

Comment: you need to find an alternative way. But it is depending a lot from our data structure. For example, you could force `bcoded_metadata` to an realistic value (ex. `zzzz`), change the index from `sparse` to normal and query for this value for the time being. But it depends how your data are populated and other parameters typical of your application.

Comment: Can you list your indexes in the question? I'll provide a worked out explanation then.

Comment: @Derick, I've updated main post with indexes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you use a sparse index for `bcoded_metadata`. If you have a sparse index on bcoded_metadata, then the index will not contain the documents that don't have the field `bcoded_metadata`. The documents without the `bcoded_metadata` field are not part of your original query, and hence "count" will return 0.

If you run just the find: `db.ts.find({"bcoded_metadata" : { "$exists" : false } })` then you won't get any results either. You can either use a non-sparse index, or do a full count with `db.ts.count();` and subtract the result of `db.ts.find({"bcoded_metadata" : { "$exists" : true } })` result.

There is a JIRA ticket that explains it a bit more, and can be tracked in case MongoDB acquires an error/warning message for this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3918

Comment: Actually i need to iterate over documents without "bcoded_metadata". 
What should I do? Is there any way to enforce dense index? Because ensureIndex({"bcoded_metadata":1},{sparce:false});
 does not work as expected, i still have sparse index after that.

Comment: Ok, I've just dropped indexes for "bcoded_metadata" and it solved problem. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of dropping that index, consider making it *not* a sparse index. Indexes by default aren't sparse, so that's something you've done yourself.