# Mongodb $exists with $or

Tags: mongodb

Let's say i have the following documents collection named students

```
{name:'John',age:16,address:'New Orleans',subject:'Maths'}

{name:'John',age:18,subject:'Maths'}
```

Now,if i want to query the documents where the subject is Maths and address is either 'New Orleans' or it doesn't exists then:

```
db.students.find({subject:'Maths',$or:[{address:{$exists:false}},{address:'New Orleans'}]})
```

But on doing the above query i only get the one with the address 'New Orleans' and not the other where i don't have the address field

What i'm i doing wrong? Any help appreciated.

**Edit:**

This question has been resolved. **Was not a query issue.** Thanks to everyone for helping out.

Comment: When you query the database with `db.students.find({subject:'Maths',{address:{$exists:false}}})` does it return any results?

Comment: @MakisTsantekidis yes i do get the document with subject Maths and no address field

Comment: Your query is correct. In the query you wrote "Orleans" in capital letter however in your data it starts with lowercase.

Comment: You have a separate text for `New Orleans`, one is written with upper case `O` and one without.

Comment: @parvin sorry for the typo, it doesn't works even if i have the correct query. Udpated my question

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refer to this question [Mongo $exists query does not return correct documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443252/mongo-exists-query-does-not-return-correct-documents)

The problem might be that you are using an index for the query (you can check that using .explain()) and the index in not indexing empty fields so it doesn't return the record that doesn't have it.

You can check that by using

`db.students.find({subject:'Maths',$or:[{address:{$exists:false}},{address:'New Orleans'}]}).hint({$natural:1})`

which will do a table scan instead of using an index (again, if you are using an index)

Answer (score 0):

I got what was the problem.

Basically one of the document where the `address` field was accidentally updated to empty string "". And since i wasn't quering that in `$or` it wasn't getting reflected in my search results. Updated my query to include importType:"" as well and now it works fine.

Thank you everyone for helping me out.